# WP Category Tag Cloud Wordpress Plugin Not Showing All Options for wordpress 4.2.2

Tags: wordpress, plugins

WP Category Tag Cloud Plugin not working with all functionality for wordpress 4.2.2

I have to filter category with tags. But available plugin not showing option for it. It showing only one filter instead of all in plugin screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that with the php code below:

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud(); ?>
```

Here you have all the options for customizing to suit your needs.

Almost always is more interesting to use codes than plugins.

Best of luck!